# Anti-aliasing - Google Font Face

Tags: firefox, fonts, typeface

Any idea how to make the font look better in FF ( win 7 ) - http://thezoomer.net/clubroyaletype/ ? I am using Google Web Font.

It looks good on ie :(

Thanks!